# Draw item from list on Name

Tags: c#, monogame

Im working in monogame and trying to draw an item from a list on name:

```
    private void MakeCards()
    {
        _cardsOnTable = new List<Card>()
        {
            new Card(CardCategory.Teachers, "Jelle"),
            new Card(CardCategory.Teachers, "Ed"),
            new Card(CardCategory.Teachers, "Silvan"),
            new Card(CardCategory.Teachers, "Richard"),

            new Card(CardCategory.Movies, "Forrest Grump"),
            new Card(CardCategory.Movies, "Toy Story"),
            new Card(CardCategory.Movies, "Dead Pool"),
            new Card(CardCategory.Movies, "Wolverine"),

            new Card(CardCategory.Places, "Toronto"),
            new Card(CardCategory.Places, "Rome"),
            new Card(CardCategory.Places, "New York"),
            new Card(CardCategory.Places, "Amsterdam")
        };
```

here is the list. this is in a different script then where i draw them:

```
public void AddBlancCard()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _game._cardsOnTable.Count; i++)
        {
            _game._cardsOnTable[i] = new Card(cardBackTexture);
            _game._cardsOnTable[i].Sprite = cardBackTexture;
            _game._cardsOnTable[i].Draw(spriteBatch);
        }
    }
```

im trying to draw the object on name but first i need to get the name from the list item. since i have png files with the exact name as the name of the list item (list item is string name)

anyone know how i can call them and fix this?

btw i draw this in a draw function i just call the addblanccard in there.  and i dont have code for the draw on name yet.

Comment: I read this as you're trying to find a card within the provided list by name. Is that correct?

Comment: im trying to get the name from the card provided in the list (like get the name of the item your standing on with the for loop) so i can draw the item by name from the png's)

Comment: Ok, in that case, can you provide the definition for the Card class? Need to know where you are storing the name.

Comment: Couldn't you set the Sprite from the constructor there btw? It seems odd to pass it in the constructor, then again for the Sprite property.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are storing the name of the card in a publicly accessible property in the Card class called "Name", you can access the name like so:

```
var name = _game._cardsOnTable[i].Name;
```

However, your underlying issue in accessing the name may be caused by data overwriting. In your for loop, you're replacing all of the cards in the list with new cards without passing back in the original object/name:

```
_game._cardsOnTable[i] = new Card(cardBackTexture);
```

Because of this, anytime you try to access the card name after that overwrite, you'll most likely get the default name string (whatever you may have that set as).